# How to mask number field as password in jsp

Tags: html, css, firefox, passwords

I have textfield that will accept only numbers. so when i enter value the value that i entered is clearly visible. i don't want user to see the entered value inside textfield.
overall that textfield should be type of number and mask as password dot.

Expected result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjvIZ.png)

Actual result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEh41.png)

Answer (score 1):

Please use input tag.

```
<input type="password">
```

Comment: if i made input as password then mobile browser number pad is not opening when i click on textfield.so that i made number field

Answer (score 1):

```css
label {
    display: block;
    font: .9rem 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

input[type='submit'],
label {
    margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
</div>

<div>
    <label for="pass">Password (8 characters minimum):</label>
    <input type="password" id="pass" name="password"
           minlength="8" required>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Sign in">
```

I hope its useful.